# Issue on page loading with pagecreate event with phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my apps "index.page", i am loading phonegap and jqm scripts inside the  tags. I have a link in my index page as below

```
<div>
    <a href="page2.html" data-ajax=false;>Click here</a>
</div>
```

If i click the above url in my index page its redirecting to "page2.html" in that page i am loading fully top to bottom html freshly. Inside "page2.html"  **head** tag same scripts phonegap & JQM js files are there. But it is not working when the page loads in pagecreate event. Find the below pagecreate event which i am having.

```
$("#page2").live('pagecreate', function(event){
     console.log("Inside page create", device.platform);
});
```

Below error is coming when the page loads from pagecreate.

```
device is not defined
console.log("Inside page create", device.platform);
```

How to load the page fully in pagecreate and want to call some function call inside this pagecreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible dont mix jQuery mobile events with phonegap.

Use this instead:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert(device.version);
}
```

Comment: Everytime i can't call deviceready right, its working inside deviceready, but not working inside pagecreate. It will not support in pagecreate event?

Comment: PhoneGap consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a PhoneGap/jQM JavaScript function before it is loaded. So you will need to create some kind of workaround. Thus device object will be available only when deviceready event is triggered. You can show ajax loader on pagecreate event and wait for deviceready. When deviceready is triggered remove ajyx loader and show nedded device info.